# Problem with datatable when I publish my site on IIS

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax, iis-8, datatables-1.10

I published a site on IIS 8 the problem is that when I want to access web pages that have a datatable I have the following error:

DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

I tried to change the path of folder of framework Datatable 1.10

I expect the display of my Datatable without errors

Here is the network report :

[image]

Here’s what I call the method in a javascript file that I include in the cshtml page :

[image]

Comment: Do not put data on c: of server which users will not be able to read.  Store any data that users need on a Network drive that users have access to.

Comment: I stock the data in the file : C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: On a IIS server users do not have access to the c: folder.  The users have guest privileges which is very limited.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn't directly find out the reason why you show this error, I suggest you could try to use remote debug for the server-side method to find out actually error message.More details about how to remote debug, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Jdweng, so where can I store the data? Knowing that there are connection rights with the active directory?

Comment: Back from vacation, I found a solution to my problem. The file path for access to the script that loads my datatable changes which is why I added a return to the parent file. Thus, /Transport/GetData replaced by  ../Transport/GetData

Comment: Use this link below [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524971/asp-net-mvc-5-ajax-controller-call-not-working-after-publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524971/asp-net-mvc-5-ajax-controller-call-not-working-after-publish)